# Revolve a non one-to-one function about the y-axis

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I am attempting to revolve $f(x)=-x(x-3)(x-2)^2$ about $x=0$. What I have come up with is that I need to redefine each interval between the relative extrema as a separate function, and then treat it as a washer problem. However, I don't have the requisite skill set to redefine the function in this way. Is there a simpler approach to this problem? A delineation of the steps would be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RevolutionPlot3D[]` supports a `RevolutionAxis` option that controls how you want to revolve the curve you are interested in. Since it treats functions in its first argument as $z=f(x)$, your requirement here corresponds to rotating about the $z$-axis. Thus,

```
RevolutionPlot3D[-x (x - 3) (x - 2)^2, {x, 0, 4}, RevolutionAxis -> {0, 0, 1}]
```

[image: some weird hat]

For comparison, here is what `RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}` does:

[image: I think I saw pottery like this once]

---

As m_goldberg notes, one can use the shorter forms `RevolutionAxis -> "Z"` or `RevolutionAxis -> "X"` instead of the explicit axis settings in the examples given above.

Comment: i think your answer is clearly the better answer rather than my paltry effort.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in function [`RevolutionPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RevolutionPlot3D.html):

```
f[x_] := -x (x - 3) (x - 2)^2
RevolutionPlot3D[f[x], {x, 0, 3}, Mesh -> None, Background -> Black, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I realize that I should have posted this in Mathematics, not Mathematica. Either way, I hope your answer helps someone. I will accept your answer when I can.

Comment: Sorry...ok, good luck :)

Comment: @fmi11 i think J.M.'s answer is clearly the better answer rather than my paltry effort.